# Wire: model in blade input box gives value with a lot of decimal points in laravel livewire

Tags: laravel, binding, nested

I am using  livewire 2.3 in my laravel 8 project. I binding Nested Data in array. I am using $this->Total_Price[$input_percentage_index] = $this->Product_qty[$input_percentage_index]*$this->Rate[$input_percentage_index]; in my livewire component. When I use laravel dd(), I have $this->Product_qty[$input_percentage_index] = 6 , $this->Rate[$input_percentage_index] = 11.2 and when I dd() my property to be used in blade then it gives me $this->Total_Price[$input_percentage_index] = 67.2. This value of 67.2 is correct as these values are multiplied. But when I model this value in blade file by using wire:model = "Total_Price.{{$index}}" then it gives value in input box as 67.1999999999999... with too many digits after decimal point.
Please guide.
Regards!!!

Answer (score 0):

you should round the number.

```php
round($float, 2)
```

it will round the result up to 2 floating decimals

Comment: I can't use round() because I have to store the values in database. And I have to know why 6*11.2 is becoming 67.19999999999 but it should be 67.2.   And it is 67.2 in livewire component but changes to 67.1999999999 in blade file. What is wrong with this.

Comment: Well, this is how float operations handled in any language. Its a common problem of probably 90% programming language. 
There should be a way to round a value, doesnt matter that you using Liveware or something else, the framework is based on php , and php does support rounding :) 

"Total_Price.{{round($index,2)}}"